# images aren't appearing in image gallery

Tags: javascript, html, css, flexbox, image-gallery

I am trying to create a swim image gallery based off of the Flex Panel Gallery from Javascript30 ([Repo Link](https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/tree/master/05%20-%20Flex%20Panel%20Gallery)). 
When trying to display the site in a browser, the images immediately go out of frame and all I can see is the background of the five flex columns on the page.

I am unsure as to why they are pushed downwards out of view in the browser and why the text (which isn't in column orientation) doesn't appear until after I click within the columns.

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

function toggleOpen() {
  console.log('Hello');
  this.classList.toggle('open');
}

function toggleActive(e) {
  console.log(e.propertyName);
  if (e.propertyName.includes('flex')) {
    this.classList.toggle('open-active');
  }
}

panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('transitionend', toggleActive));
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lightblue;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.image-panels {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  background: #6B0F9C;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition:
    font-size 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.51, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11),
    flex 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11),
    background 0.2s;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#first-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

#second-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

#third-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

#fourth-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

#fifth-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

.panel > * {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel > *:first-child {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.panel.open-active > *:first-child {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.panel > *:last-child {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.panel.open-active > *:last-child {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.panel div p {
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72), 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  font-size: 2em;
}

.panel div p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 4em;
}

.panel.open {
  flex: 5;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Swim Club Image Gallery</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="image-panels">
      <div class="panel">
        <div id="first-panel">
          <p>Join</p>
          <p>This</p>
          <p>Quarter!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <div id="second-panel">
          <p>Swimming</p>
          <p>Is</p>
          <p>Fun!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <div id="third-panel">
          <p>Every</p>
          <p>Husky</p>
          <p>Is Welcome!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <div id="fourth-panel">
          <p>Recreational</p>
          <p>Swim</p>
          <p>Atmosphere!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="panel">
        <div id="fifth-panel">
          <p>Best</p>
          <p>Club</p>
          <p>To Stay Fit!</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By watching the [repo](https://github.com/wesbos/JavaScript30/blob/master/05%20-%20Flex%20Panel%20Gallery/index-FINISHED.html) site example, you should apply the image background to parent div, like this:

```html
<div class="panel" id="first-panel">
  <p>Join</p>
  <p>This</p>
  <p>Quarter!</p>
</div>
```

```js
const panels = document.querySelectorAll('.panel');

function toggleOpen() {
  console.log('Hello');
  this.classList.toggle('open');
}

function toggleActive(e) {
  console.log(e.propertyName);
  if (e.propertyName.includes('flex')) {
    this.classList.toggle('open-active');
  }
}

panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen));
panels.forEach(panel => panel.addEventListener('transitionend', toggleActive));
```

```css
body {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  background: lightblue;
  font-family: "Source Sans Pro", sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 200;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

.image-panels {
  min-height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
}

.panel {
  display: flex;
  background: #6B0F9C;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  transition:
    font-size 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.51, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11),
    flex 0.7s cubic-bezier(0.61, -0.19, 0.7, -0.11),
    background 0.2s;
  font-size: 20px;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  flex: 1;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
}

#first-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

#second-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

#third-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

#fourth-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

#fifth-panel {
  background-image: url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/2500/1667);
}

.panel > * {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform 0.5s;
  flex: 1 0 auto;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.panel > *:first-child {
  transform: translateY(-100%);
}

.panel.open-active > *:first-child {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.panel > *:last-child {
  transform: translateY(100%);
}

.panel.open-active > *:last-child {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.panel div p {
  text-shadow: 0 0 4px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.72), 0 0 14px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.45);
  font-size: 2em;
}

.panel div p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 4em;
}

.panel.open {
  flex: 5;
  font-size: 40px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Sans+Pro&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <title>Swim Club Image Gallery</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="image-panels">
      <div class="panel" id="first-panel">
        <p>Join</p>
        <p>This</p>
        <p>Quarter!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel" id="second-panel">
        <p>Swimming</p>
        <p>Is</p>
        <p>Fun!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel" id="third-panel">
        <p>Every</p>
        <p>Husky</p>
        <p>Is Welcome!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel" id="fourth-panel">
        <p>Recreational</p>
        <p>Swim</p>
        <p>Atmosphere!</p>
      </div>
      <div class="panel" id="fifth-panel">
        <p>Best</p>
        <p>Club</p>
        <p>To Stay Fit!</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="index.js">
    </script>
  </body>

</html>
```